Solana SPL wallet
I used solana airdrop 1 command in solana spl wallet and got 1 sol. I had 0.5 real sol in that same wallet. Solscan is showing 0.5 but when i check by solana balance command it is saying 1. I want use my real solana in solana spl. Could anyone please help me?
